# Permission Denied Error Python

Tags: python, permission-denied

I am new to python and I am trying to open a file that contains a number of documents. I am using visual studio, this file is in the current directory (the same directory of the project files which are in) and I have added the file to the project in the IDE. The line of code is below:

```
file = open("name_of_file")
```

I am getting the following error: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'name_of_file'`

I hope this is a very simple fix? I tried to google it and look at some of the other posts, but had trouble following them. What are the reasons why this would happen?

Comment: Obviously, you don't have permission to read the file.

Comment: It might be that the file is already open in another application.

Comment: @alfasin: no, chmod 400 is enough for a user to read the file. 777 is just needlessly bad. Also, I think Visual Studio is Windows only?

Comment: Since you're mentioning visual studio I assume that's windows. Make sure the file is not open anywhere else, reboot your computer if you're not sure, then try again.

Comment: I tried changing file permissions manually in windows explorer, made sure file was closed, and rebooted. I also got permission denied when I ran python in the windows command line and tried to open the file from there. I finally got it to work when I imported os library and used the os.walk function as follows:[import os... for file in os.walk("name_of_file"):]

Comment: If `os.walk` worked then "name_of_file" was a directory name and the file you wanted wasn't in the current directory. In fact, the current directory may not be where you think it is. `print(os.getcwd())` would tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the permissions with `os.chmod` function: `os.chmod(path, mode)`, where `mode` is is numeric form (try with 777 to be sure). If this is not working, as Britt mentioned, it might be that the file is open in another application.

Comment: OP is on Windows. This likely isn't a rights issue and chmod may not be a good solution on windows anyway.

Comment: Well, I remember using Python's `os.chmod` on Windows, and it solved my problem. I think it's worth trying.